# JOOQ Forced types to convert a BigInteger to BigDecimal for POSTGRES

Tags: java, sql, jooq

for a Table , lets say myTable, I have a column myColumn..

the default JOOQ generation creates myColumn as BigInteger,

I want to create it as BigDecimal.

This is the converter I am using.

```
public class myConverter extends AbstractConverter<BigInteger, BigDecimal> {

    public BigIntToBigDecConverter(Class<BigInteger> fromType, Class<BigDecimal> toType) {

        super(fromType, toType);
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal from(BigInteger databaseObject) {
        return new BigDecimal(databaseObject);
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger to(BigDecimal userObject) {
        return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(userObject.intValue()));
    }
}
```

How should be the forceType configuration look like in the XML file?

Comment: What have you tried [from here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/)? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @LukasEder 

I have tried this 


```
            <forcedTypes>
                <forcedType>
                    <userType>java.math.BigDecimal</userType>
                    <converter>xyz.myclass.BigIntToBigDecConverter</converter>
                    <types>BigInteger\.*</types>
                    <includeExpression>*</includeExpression>
                </forcedType>
            </forcedTypes>
```

logs are not showing any concrete errors.

Comment: You can edit your question, to add more details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your columns are generated as `BigInteger` is because they're of type `NUMERIC(n, 0)`, `NUMBER(n, 0)`, or `DECIMAL(n, 0)` depending on the dialect you're using, but the key here is that the scale is `0`, and `n` is large enough that it doesn't fit in a `Long` anymore.

The reason why your `<forcedType/>` configuration hasn't worked is because the type you've listed in `<types/>` is the Java type `BigInteger`, not the `SQLDataType`, [see documentation here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/). In order to rewrite all zero scale decimals to produce `BigDecimal`, just write this:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <name>NUMERIC</name>
  <inputTypes>(?i:(NUMERIC|NUMBER|DECIMAL)\(\d+,0\))</inputTypes>
</forcedType>
```

You won't need a custome converter for that

Comment: What if I want to do this for a single column of a particular table

Comment: Then just add the usual `<includeExpression>` regular expression to the `<forcedType>`